# Image manipulation and storing in Dart

Tags: java, web-applications, dart

I'm looking for some help about Dart Language.

I'm not a professional developer, so I don't know all the resources of many languages, except for Java, with which I'm developing a small "World Cup TOP 5" web application where the user can select five teams and then publish the selection on its Facebook timeline.

Right now, in Java code, the application is doing its job. It's loading the default image background and using Graphics2D.drawImage to add the teams' PNGs over it. Then, it saves the finished file in a temporary directory and publishes it on Facebook.

However, I read some articles saying that Dart can do all the job for me, not just the frontend.

So, my question is: how can I do that in Dart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [image](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image) package, I'm not sure if it supports all your requirements but it's a good start.

Comment: This is what I fear: is Dart a limited language in comparison with Java? I mean, maybe some jobs Dart won't handle?

Comment: No that's not the problem, but library is still under active development and might miss some features. But adding a logo to another images is simple.